# Using $\epsilon-\delta$ language to show $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}=0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I've permitted myself to use $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, as I've proven this.

Here's some manipulation I've tried, but I can't quite get the $1+\cos(x)$ terms in the denominators bounded, so I don't think this approach will be fruitful:

$$|\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}|=|\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{x(1+\cos(x))}|=|\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x(1+\cos(x))}|=|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}|=|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}|=|\frac{\sin(x)-x+x}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}|=|(\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x}+1)\cdot(\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)})|=|\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x}\cdot \frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}+\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos(x)}|$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using inequality
$$|\sin\alpha|\leq|\alpha|$$
then
$$\left|\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}\right|=\left|\dfrac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{x}\right|\leq\left|\dfrac{2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}{x}\right|=\left|\frac{x}{2}\right|$$

Comment: Alternatively, $2\sin^2(x/2)/x = (x/2)[\sin(x/2)/(x/2)]^2$ and he can use $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(x)/x = 1$.

Comment: @Nosrati Would this proof also extend to $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2})=\frac{1}{2}$ by way of the following?: Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta=\epsilon$ (or any positive real).

Then, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|x-0|<\delta\Rightarrow |\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}|=|\frac{2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}|\le |\frac{2(\frac{x}{2})^2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}|=0<\epsilon$.

Comment: No. . . . . . .

Comment: In this case use $$\cos x<1-\dfrac12x^2+\dfrac{1}{4!}x^4$$

Comment: $$|\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}|=|\frac{2\cos x+x^2-2}{2x^2}|\leq |\frac{1}{24}{x^2}|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Why does the proof not extend as demonstrated? I cannot seem to find any error in the argument; it seems to comply perfectly with the definition of a limit of a function.

Comment: This is incorrect $$|\frac{2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}|\le |\frac{2(\frac{x}{2})^2}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}|$$